# Forecasting using LSTM-RNN Python

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, forecasting

I am using LSTM - RNN for Sales forecasting.

I have already trained and validated my model in the ratio of 70-30. I have around 144 rows of data which includes 2 columns (Date (YYYY/MM) and Sales).
I am only using the sales column to predict values.

I need to know whether it is possible to train 100% of your dataset. And If so, how do I predict the immediate future values (Out of Sample Data). What should be given as input for the model? Since I am kinda new to Deep Learning, this might be something easy that I am missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the input and output shapes of the model you have trained so far?

Comment: @SaTa My Input Shape for the model is (113, 1, 30) and my Output Shape is (113, 1).

Comment: Can you elaborate further? Is 113 number of training samples, 1 time steps, and 30 the features?

Comment: @SaTa Yeah I think so. I am using 113 training samples and my look back is 30, which means I am trying to predict the 31st value and so on.

Comment: In this case, you should reshape your input data into (113, 30, 1). LSTM data format is (n_samples, n_timesteps, n_features). With n_timesteps as 1 rather than 30, you are really gaining anything by using LSTM. It will perform similar to a ANN.